# How to find functions a and b in Stochastic differential equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I have to solve simple task using Ito's formula. The goal is to find
$$ E[\sin(\sigma W_t)] $$ where $W_t$ is Wiener process.

I know that we have to use function
$$ F(t,x)=\sin(\sigma x) $$
and then Ito's formula.

I know that
$$ dx(t)=a(t)dt+b(t)dW(t) $$
However I do not see why im my exercise I should take functions $a(t)=0, b(t)=1$ because we do have neither $dt$ nor $dW(t)$. To sum up I want to ask how to find those functions in that kind of exercises.

Comment: You want to use the Ito's lemma. You have to write $W_t$ as an Ito process. So


$$ dW_t = 0dt+1dW_t$$